# python list comprehension VS for behaviour

Tags: python, list-comprehension

EDIT: stupid logic of mine got ahead of me. The none are just the returns from the comprehension call.
Ok, I'm running some tests in python, and I ran into a bit of a difference in execution orders, which leads me to an understanding of how it is implemented, but I'd like to run it by you fine people to see if I'm right or there is more to it. Consider this code:

```
>>> a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> def test(self,arg):
...     print "testing %s" %(arg)
...     a.pop()
... 
>>>[test(elem) for elem in a]
testing a
testing b
testing c
[None, None, None]
>>> a
['a', 'b']
#now we try another syntax
>>> a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> for elem in a:
...     print "elem is %s"%(elem)
...     test(elem)
... 
elem is a
testing a
elem is b
testing b
elem is c
testing c
>>> a
['a', 'b']
>>>
```

Now this tells me that the for elem in a: gets the next iteratable element then applies the body, whereas the comprehension somehow calls the function on each element of the list before actually executing the code in the function, so modifying the list from the function ( pop) leads to the ]none, none, none]

Is this right? what is happening here?

thanks

Comment: `test()` does not return anything, hence it returns `None`. (BTW, you should delete the `self` parameter.)

Comment: yes, I'm just playing around I wanted to see if they were really equivalent... but there is something to the execution order here.

Comment: Resizing a collection (adding or deleting items) while iterating over it is a punishable offense.

Comment: yes of course, I'm not debating that

Comment: The forloop and list comprehension have to same effect in this case? They both print "testing a,testing b,testing c" and `a==['a','b']` afterwards. What is the difference???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `test` function has no `return` statement, thus using it in a list comprehension results in a list of `None`s. The interactive python prompt prints out whatever the last statement returns.

Example:

```
>>> def noop(x): pass
... 
>>> [noop(i) for i in range(5)]
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

So really there's no difference in how the list comprehension and `for` loop in your question work.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
>>> i = iter(a)
>>> next(i)
'a'
>>> a.pop()
'e'
>>> next(i)
'b'
>>> a.pop()
'd'
>>> next(i)
'c'
>>> a.pop()
'c'
>>> next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has got to `"c"`, then ran out of elements in the list. As `test` returns nothing, you get `[None, None, None]`.